# Remove Identity from a column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a 5GB table (nearly 500 million rows) and we want to remove the identity property on one of the column, but when we try to do this through SSMS - it times out.

Can this be done through T-SQL?

Comment: Can you post the schema of the table here?

Comment: I'm sure there are excellent reasons that SQL Server doesn't support removing an identity property from a column via a simple ALTER TABLE ... statement, but it's nevertheless making me sad currently that that's the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server how to drop identity from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702745/sql-server-how-to-drop-identity-from-a-column) (which is seems specific to [[tag:sql-server-2005]], but suggests the same approaches anyway)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You cannot remove an `IDENTITY` specification once set.

To remove the entire column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
DROP COLUMN yourCOlumn;
```

Information about [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) here

If you need to keep the data, but remove the `IDENTITY` column, you will need to:

- Create a new column
- Transfer the data from the existing `IDENTITY` column to the new column
- Drop the existing `IDENTITY` column.
- Rename the new column to the original column name

Comment: you can remove an Identity spec. In fact I had to do it yesterday using SSMS although not on 500 million rows.

Comment: @simon if you script out your changes, you'll see SSMS is actually creating a copy of the table w/o the identity property.

Comment: I just want to add to rename the new column to the original column's name. Also, if this `identity` column is used as part of a `foreign key` in another table, you're going to have to drop the constraints first, then take action as @AdamWenger mentioned about removing the identity `attribute/property` ..You can also look into this link for more details about removing the attribute only: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/ ..Good luck!

Comment: To the person who down-voted - I would appreciate hearing what you did not like about my answer.

Comment: Take a look at Mark Sowul's answer below.  Obviates the need to move data from column to column.  Using Mark's answer you are only shuffling metadata.  No big deal unless you are working on a table that has tens or hundreds of millions of rows.  Plus Mark's answer prevents the relocation of the column in the table schema.  I just tried it and it worked like a charm.  Very clever.

Answer (score 152):

If you want to do this **without adding and populating a new column**, **without reordering the columns**, and **with almost no downtime** because no data is changing on the table, let's do some magic with partitioning functionality (but since no partitions are used you don't need Enterprise edition):

1. Remove all foreign keys that point to this table
2. Script the table to be created; rename everything e.g. 'MyTable2', 'MyIndex2', etc.
   Remove the IDENTITY specification.
3. You should now have two "identical"-ish tables, one full, the other empty with no IDENTITY.
4. Run `ALTER TABLE [Original] SWITCH TO [Original2]`
5. Now your original table will be empty and the new one will have the data.  You have switched the metadata for the two tables (instant).
6. Drop the original (now-empty table), `exec sys.sp_rename` to rename the various schema objects back to the original names, and then you can recreate your foreign keys.

For example, given:

```
CREATE TABLE Original
(
  Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, Value NVARCHAR(300)
);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Original_Value ON Original (Value);

INSERT INTO Original
SELECT 'abcd'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'defg';
```

You can do the following:

```
--create new table with no IDENTITY
CREATE TABLE Original2
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY
, Value NVARCHAR(300)
);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Original_Value2 ON Original2 (Value);

--data before switch
SELECT 'Original', *
FROM Original
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Original2', *
FROM Original2;

ALTER TABLE Original SWITCH TO Original2;

--data after switch
SELECT 'Original', *
FROM Original
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Original2', *
FROM Original2;

--clean up 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Original) DROP TABLE Original;
EXEC sys.sp_rename 'Original2.IX_Original_Value2', 'IX_Original_Value', 'INDEX';
EXEC sys.sp_rename 'Original2', 'Original', 'OBJECT';


UPDATE Original
SET Id = Id + 1;

SELECT *
FROM Original;
```

---

For the record, as this has become increasingly popular, I have wanted to track down the original source (I didn't think of it myself), but of course I've long forgotten where I found the original idea.  It may have been here; this was the only one I could find predating this answer (time flies, boys and girls): https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17738.sql-server-quick-way-to-remove-the-identity-property.aspx

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It is the only real way to remove an identity column without massive data migration.

Comment: If using SQL Management Studio to script out the table, be sure to turn on Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting > Table and view options > Script indexes (False by default)

Comment: This is great.  Note that you do not need to use new names for the indices.  As you can see in the code that renames an index, index names are scoped to the table, so you can have identical index names in two different tables.  However, the same is not true for constraints and triggers.  For those, you must use unique names, as shown here for indices.

Comment: Incidentally it's even easier if you just use a different schema for the second table -- then you don't need to rename anything (so you can pretty much copy and paste the 'generate table' script and just alter the schema name).  Once done, you can use `ALTER SCHEMA [original schema] TRANSFER [new schema].[table]`

Comment: However, beware: `ALTER SCHEMA ... TRANSFER` does a lot more locking (https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/staging-data-locking-danger-with-alter-schema-transfer/)

Comment: @kuklei Steps 1 and 6 point out that you need to drop and recreate the foreign keys.  If it takes less time to rebuild the entire table than it takes to recreate the foreign keys, then yes, the SSMS table designer is easier.  But on large tables it takes a very long time to use the SSMS designer to rebuild the table (during which time the data is inaccessible), and sometimes it's impossible because it will fill up the transaction log, and/or because while the table is being rebuilt it takes up twice the space in the data file.

Comment: Sorry @MarkSowul. Missed the last few words in point 6 after the comma. Your solution is good for large tables and can be combined with the SSMS scripting capabilities to generate the drop and create of foreign key columns before and after the switch statement. Good one

Comment: This is a brilliant solution, thanks (5 years later...). After step 4, once the original table is empty, I dropped the identity using SSMS's design option, and then ran ALTER TABLE [Original2] SWITCH TO [Original] to put all the data back in the original table.

Comment: Remeber to drop the Foreign Key constraints at the beginning and set again at the end of the process. Thanks!

Comment: Don't Forget to script-out any Extended Attributes!  And make sure to CHECK CHECK those FKs.  And DEFAULT CONSTRAINT names (caught me on that one) must be unique per DB, so there's more sp_rename activity after Original-DROP.  Saved me untold hours on a 500M-row, 70 FK central table. HUGE THANKS, @MarkSowul

Answer (score 65):

This gets messy with foreign and primary key constraints, so here's some scripts to help you on your way:

First, create a duplicate column with a temporary name:

```
alter table yourTable add tempId int NOT NULL default -1;
update yourTable set tempId = id;
```

Next, get the name of your primary key constraint:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable';
```

Now try drop the primary key constraint for your column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_yourTable_id;
```

If you have foreign keys, it will fail, so if so drop the foreign key constraints.  **KEEP TRACK OF WHICH TABLES YOU RUN THIS FOR SO YOU CAN ADD THE CONSTRAINTS BACK IN LATER!!!**

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'otherTable';
alter table otherTable drop constraint fk_otherTable_yourTable;
commit;
..
```

Once all of your foreign key constraints have been removed, you'll be able to remove the PK constraint, drop that column, rename your temp column, and add the PK constraint to that column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_yourTable_id;
alter table yourTable drop column id;
EXEC sp_rename 'yourTable.tempId', 'id', 'COLUMN';
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_yourTable_id PRIMARY KEY (id) 
commit;
```

Finally, add the FK constraints back in:

```
alter table otherTable add constraint fk_otherTable_yourTable foreign key (yourTable_id) references yourTable(id);
..
```

El Fin!

Comment: pay attention to your sql server version, I tried in azure sql server, not all operations here is supported in azure version sql.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Helped me a lot!
You just should add a verification for indexes that reference the column.  Something like:

`Select 
     t.name 'Table',
     i.name 'Index',
     c.name 'Column',
  i.is_primary_key,
  i.is_unique
From sys.tables t 
Inner Join sys.indexes i On i.object_id = t.object_id 
Inner Join sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id And i.index_id = ic.index_id 
Inner Join sys.columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id and ic.column_id = c.column_id 
Where t.name = 'tableName'
Order By t.name, i.name, i.index_id, ic.index_column_id`

Comment: good trick, helped me lot, But one point, I want to mention here is that, When we add a new duplicate column as mentioned in 1st step, it added at the end but generally we want that our primary key column i.e. Id to be the 1st column in that table. So is there any workaround to that?

Answer (score 24):

I just had this same problem.  4 statements in SSMS instead of using the GUI and it was very fast.

- Make a new column

  `alter table users add newusernum int;`
- Copy values over

  `update users set newusernum=usernum;`
- Drop the old column

  `alter table users drop column usernum;`
- Rename the new column to the old column name

  `EXEC sp_RENAME 'users.newusernum' , 'usernum', 'COLUMN';`

Comment: It's not this simple if you have any constraints on the old column.

Answer (score 14):

Following script removes Identity field for a column named 'Id'

Hope it helps.

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_rename '[SomeTable].[Id]', 'OldId';

    ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] ADD Id int NULL

    EXEC ('UPDATE [SomeTable] SET Id = OldId')

    ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

    ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_constraintName];
    ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] DROP COLUMN OldId
    ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] ALTER COLUMN [Id] INTEGER NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_JobInfo PRIMARY KEY (Id)

    ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN   
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE ()
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 5):

Bellow code working as fine, **when we don't know identity column name**.

Need to copy data into new temp table like `Invoice_DELETED`. 
and next time we using:

```
insert into Invoice_DELETED select * from Invoice where ...


SELECT t1.*
INTO Invoice_DELETED
FROM Invoice t1
LEFT JOIN Invoice ON 1 = 0
--WHERE t1.InvoiceID = @InvoiceID
```

For more explanation see: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138345/101038

Comment: LOVE YAAAAAAAAAA. Exactly what I was looking for, an easy way to avoid generating "IDENTITY" from a "SELECT * INTO" (to create a new table temp for backups that need)

Comment: it is small and beauty ;)

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server you can turn on and off identity insert like this:

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON

-- run your queries here

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name OFF

Comment: Was just going to post the same.  I am not sure this functionality existed when the OP happened.  But this is definitely the solution now.

Comment: this is the solution that worked for me; Im using a mySQL Server 2019 database.

Comment: and you have to specify full column list with this option

Comment: This is a very buggy solution. For example, SSMS cannot do this if you want to insert into more than a single table with identity columns. You would need to split the SQL script into multiple ones, one per table. It's better to get rid of the indentity property for good, if you can. It's like this functionality was developed by a high-school student with good intentions, but bad technical skills.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename add newcolumn int
update tablename set newcolumn=existingcolumnname
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN existingcolumnname;
EXEC sp_RENAME 'tablename.oldcolumn' , 'newcolumnname', 'COLUMN'
```

However above code works only if no primary-foreign key relation

Comment: Yes, but it rewrites every row of the table so it's inappropriate for large tables.

Answer (score 1):

Just for someone who have the same problem I did.
If you just want to make some insert just once you can do something like this.

Lets suppose you have a table with two columns

```
ID Identity (1,1) | Name Varchar
```

and want to insert a row with the ID = 4. So you Reseed it to 3 so the next one is 4

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT([YourTable], RESEED, 3)
```

Make the Insert

```
INSERT  INTO [YourTable]
        ( Name )
VALUES  ( 'Client' )
```

And get your seed back to the highest ID, lets suppose is 15

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT([YourTable], RESEED, 15)
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement, and you could try this way, which I personally recommend you, please manually design your table and generate the script, and what I did below was renaming the old table and also its constraint for backup.

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SI_Provider_Profile
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF_SI_Provider_Profile_SIdtDateTimeStamp
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SI_Provider_Profile
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF_SI_Provider_Profile_SIbHotelPreLoaded
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_SI_Provider_Profile
    (
    SI_lProvider_Profile_ID int NOT NULL,
    SI_lSerko_Integrator_Token_ID int NOT NULL,
    SI_sSerko_Integrator_Provider varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SI_sSerko_Integrator_Profile varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SI_dtDate_Time_Stamp datetime NOT NULL,
    SI_lProvider_ID int NULL,
    SI_sDisplay_Name varchar(10) NULL,
    SI_lPurchased_From int NULL,
    SI_sProvider_UniqueID varchar(255) NULL,
    SI_bHotel_Pre_Loaded bit NOT NULL,
    SI_sSiteName varchar(255) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_SI_Provider_Profile SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_SI_Provider_Profile ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_SI_Provider_Profile_SIdtDateTimeStamp DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR SI_dtDate_Time_Stamp
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_SI_Provider_Profile ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_SI_Provider_Profile_SIbHotelPreLoaded DEFAULT ((0)) FOR SI_bHotel_Pre_Loaded
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.SI_Provider_Profile)
        EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_SI_Provider_Profile (SI_lProvider_Profile_ID, SI_lSerko_Integrator_Token_ID, SI_sSerko_Integrator_Provider, SI_sSerko_Integrator_Profile, SI_dtDate_Time_Stamp, SI_lProvider_ID, SI_sDisplay_Name, SI_lPurchased_From, SI_sProvider_UniqueID, SI_bHotel_Pre_Loaded, SI_sSiteName)
        SELECT SI_lProvider_Profile_ID, SI_lSerko_Integrator_Token_ID, SI_sSerko_Integrator_Provider, SI_sSerko_Integrator_Profile, SI_dtDate_Time_Stamp, SI_lProvider_ID, SI_sDisplay_Name, SI_lPurchased_From, SI_sProvider_UniqueID, SI_bHotel_Pre_Loaded, SI_sSiteName FROM dbo.SI_Provider_Profile WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO

-- Rename the primary key constraint or unique key In SQL Server constraints such as primary keys or foreign keys are objects in their own right, even though they are dependent upon the "containing" table.
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.SI_Provider_Profile.PK_SI_Provider_Profile', 'PK_SI_Provider_Profile_Old';
GO
-- backup old table in case of 
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.SI_Provider_Profile', N'SI_Provider_Profile_Old', 'OBJECT'
GO

EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_SI_Provider_Profile', N'SI_Provider_Profile', 'OBJECT'
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.SI_Provider_Profile ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_SI_Provider_Profile PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
    SI_lProvider_Profile_ID
    ) WITH( PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following of ["Mark Sowul" 's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26048363/10027033)

For example you have 3 tables like this, with two foreign key

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Table_1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NULL
    )
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Table_1_Index   
    ON [Table_1] ([Name]);

CREATE TABLE [Table_2](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Table_1]([id]) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    [car] [varchar](10) NULL
    )
GO

CREATE TABLE [Table_3](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Table_1]([Name])
    )
GO

insert into [Table_1] Values('John'),('Mike')
insert into [Table_2] Values(10000, 'Benz'),(10000, 'Volvo'),(10001, 'BMW')
insert into [Table_3] Values('John')
GO
```

If you want remove identity from "id" column from "Table_1" Table with "dbo" Schema, run this query

**Query:**

```
Declare @Schema SysName = 'dbo'
Declare @TableName SysName = 'Table_1'
Declare @ColumnName SysName = 'id'

Declare @Table_Name SYSNAME = QUOTENAME(@Schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@TableName)
Declare @SQLCreateTable NVARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @SQLFK NVARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

--get foreign keys
;with fk_columns AS 
(
    select constraint_object_id, OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id) KeyName, OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) FKTable, OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) PKTable,
    COL_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id, parent_column_id) FKColumn, COL_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id, referenced_column_id) PKColumn,
    delete_referential_action, update_referential_action, is_not_trusted
    from sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
    on fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    WHERE fkc.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name)
)
SELECT @SQLFK = ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + fk.FKTable + ' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE ' CHECK' 
              END + 
              ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.KeyName  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.FKColumn + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')' +
              ' REFERENCES '+@Table_Name+' ('
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.PKColumn + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE '' 
              END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE '' 
              END 
            + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + fk.FKTable + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.KeyName  + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM fk_columns fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')

--drop foreign keys
;with fk_columns AS 
(
    select OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id) KeyName, OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) FKTable
    from sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
    on fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    WHERE fkc.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name)
)
SELECT @SQL = ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + fk.FKTable +
              ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + fk.KeyName  + ']' 
            + CHAR(13)
        FROM fk_columns fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--find not exist table name
Declare @i int = 1
WHILE OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@Schema) + '.' +QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '_Temp' + Cast(@i AS varchar), 'U') IS NOT NULL
    SET @i+=1
Declare @TempName SysName = @TableName + '_Temp' + Cast(@i AS varchar)
Declare @Temp_Name SysName = QUOTENAME(@Schema) + '.' +QUOTENAME(@TableName + '_Temp' + Cast(@i AS varchar))

--create temp table like table code
DECLARE @object_id INT = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name)
;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
          ic.[object_id]
        , ic.index_id
        , ic.is_descending_key
        , ic.is_included_column
        , c.name
    FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
),
fk_columns AS 
(
     SELECT 
          k.constraint_object_id
        , cname = c.name
        , rcname = rc.name
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
)
SELECT @SQLCreateTable = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @Temp_Name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
            THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
            ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    WHEN tp.name IN ('decimal', 'numeric')
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 AND COL_NAME(ic.object_id, ic.column_id) <> @ColumnName THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' ELSE '' END 
        END + CHAR(13)
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
    ORDER BY c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
    + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                    (SELECT STUFF((
                         SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                         FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                         JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                         WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                             AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                             AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
            + ')' + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)
    + ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + @Temp_Name + ' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE ' CHECK' 
              END + 
              ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')' +
              ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE '' 
              END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE '' 
              END 
            + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @Temp_Name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
        WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
    + ISNULL(((SELECT
         CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END
                + CASE i.type WHEN 1 THEN ' CLUSTERED' ELSE ' NONCLUSTERED' END
                + ' INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON ' + @Temp_Name + ' (' +
                STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                FROM index_column c
                WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                    AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
                    FROM index_column c
                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
        WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
            AND i.is_primary_key = 0
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ), '')

--rename primary key constaint on column from table
Declare @PrimaryName SYSNAME
SELECT @PrimaryName=i.name
    from sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
    ON i.object_id = ic.object_id and i.index_id = ic.index_id
    where i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name) and Col_Name(ic.object_id, column_id) = @ColumnName and is_primary_key = 1
SET @SQL = N'EXEC sp_rename ' + @PrimaryName + ', ' + 'ThisMustNotBeExist'+ @PrimaryName + ', N''OBJECT'''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
--rename index on column from table
Declare @IndexName SYSNAME
SELECT @IndexName=i.name
    from sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
    ON i.object_id = ic.object_id and i.index_id = ic.index_id
    where i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name) and Col_Name(ic.object_id, column_id) = @ColumnName and is_primary_key = 0
SET @SQL = N'EXEC sp_rename ' + @Table_Name + '.' + @IndexName + ', ' + 'ThisMustNotBeExist'+ @IndexName + ', N''INDEX''' 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--run create temp table like table code
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLCreateTable

--Move table data to temp data
SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE '+ @Table_Name + ' SWITCH TO ' + @Temp_Name
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--check clean up 
SET @SQL = N'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '+ @Table_Name + ') THROW 50000, ''Table is not clear'', 1'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--drop table
SET @SQL = N'DROP TABLE '+ @Table_Name
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--rename temp table to table
EXEC sys.sp_rename @Temp_Name, @TableName, 'OBJECT';

--create foreign keys
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLFK
```

**Important Attention:**

- **This Code only copy keys and indexes, if you have other things on that table, you loose them after running this code**

if you want copy triggers or extended property of the table too, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77526529/10027033) and add @SQL2 and @SQL3 to @SQLCreateTable before execute it

Answer (score -1):

`ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN columnName DROP IDENTITY IF EXISTS;`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: This does not work with SQL Server 14 (2017): `[S0001][156] Line 1: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'.`

Answer (score -2):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY (COLUMN_NAME DROP IDENTITY);
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. Care to explain? [answer].

Comment: I got sent here looking for a solution for oracle. The given sql does work on oracle

Comment: It doesn't work on SQL SERVER

Comment: `[S0001][102] Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.` on SQL Server 2017