# Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove identity from a column by updating it like this..

```
sp_configure 'allow update', 1 
go 

reconfigure with override 
go

update sys.syscolumns 
set colstat = 0    -- turn off bit 1 which indicates identity column 
where id = object_id('tbl1') and name = 'ids'
go

sp_configure 'allow updates', 0 
go 

reconfigure 
go
```

I am getting this error, tried many times.

> Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

Comment: There are lots of suggested solutions here:   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=Ad+hoc+updates+to+system+catalogs+are+not+allowed.&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=Ad+hoc+updates+to+system+catalogs+are+not+allowed.&gs_l=hp...0j0i22i30.0.0.1.209060...........0.wph1AZZRtto

Comment: Well - the error says it all and very clearly: **updates to system catalogs are not allowed** - those are **system-level** catalog views - you have no business fiddling around in them and trying to update stuff - these views reflect the reality of your system - if you want to change something - change it in the respective database object (here: in `tbl1`) - not in the system catalog view!

Comment: Seriously, doing this will likely just break something.  Just [drop and recreate the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230257/sql-server-remove-identity-from-a-column-in-a-table).

Comment: I want to do it any way I simply want to Remove Identity Property from a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of it completely, just rename the table and then dump the data into a new table.

```
EXEC sp_rename 'OriginalTblName','OLD_OriginalTblName'

CREATE TABLE OriginalTblName (Definition of your Table)

INSERT OriginalTblName
SELECT * FROM OLD_OriginalTblName
```

You can skip the `CREATE TABLE` step if you want by just selecting the contents into the new table.  You lose the ability to define the fields the way you want with this method.

```
SELECT * FROM OLD_OriginalTblName
INTO OriginalTblName
```

If you are just wanting to `INSERT` new records, you can use `IDENTITY INSERT` to insert the records you want.  Just be careful not to duplicate the values or you will break the table.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON OriginalTblName

INSERT OriginalTblName
SELECT someFields
FROM someTbl

SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF OriginalTblName
```

`IDENTITY INSERT` will not work for `UPDATE` on the `IDENTITY` field.  You will need to capture the data and reinsert the record with one of the methods described above.