# How to update 2 sqlserver tables using 2 query with having identity column in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

By using this two queries separately for update tables,I could update only PO table.When i try to update PO_Cart table(which relates to datagridview) it said i cannot update identity column.What can i do now to solve this

```
public void UpdatePurchseOrderTable(int PO_No,int Supplier_ID, string Date, string RequiredDate, decimal GrandTotal)
    {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
        con.mysqlconnection();
        string query = "UPDATE TBL_PO "
            + " SET Supplier_ID = @Supplier_ID,Date = @Date,"
            + "RequiredDate = @RequiredDate,GrandTotal=@GrandTotal"
             + " WHERE PO_No = @PO_No";
        con.sqlquery(query);
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PO_No", SqlDbType.Int));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@PO_No"].Value = PO_No;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Supplier_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@Supplier_ID"].Value = Supplier_ID;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.Date));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = Date;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequiredDate", SqlDbType.Date));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@RequiredDate"].Value = RequiredDate;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GrandTotal", SqlDbType.Money));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@GrandTotal"].Value = GrandTotal;
        con.nonquery();
    }

public void UpdatePOCartTable(int PO_No,string ISBN_No, decimal UnitPrice, int OrderQuantity, decimal Total)
    {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
        con.mysqlconnection();
        string query = "UPDATE TBL_PO_Cart"
            + " SET ISBN_No=@ISBN_No,UnitPrice=@UnitPrice,"
            + "OrderQuantity=@OrderQuantity,Total=@Total"
            + "WHERE PO_No = @PO_No";
        con.sqlquery(query);
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PO_No", SqlDbType.Int));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@PO_No"].Value = PO_No;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ISBN_No", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@ISBN_No"].Value = ISBN_No;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.Date));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@UnitPrice"].Value = UnitPrice;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OrderQuantity", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@OrderQuantity"].Value = OrderQuantity;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Total", SqlDbType.Money));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@Total"].Value = Total;
        con.nonquery();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax of updating from Join is similar to MySQL. However it is different in SQL Server

```
UPDATE TBL_PO
SET TBL_PO.PO_No=@PO_No,TBL_PO.Supplier_ID = @Supplier_ID,TBL_PO.Date = @Date,
TBL_PO.RequiredDate = @RequiredDate,TBL_PO.GrandTotal=@GrandTotal,
FROM TBL_PO 
INNER JOIN TBL_PO_Cart ON TBL_PO_Cart.PO_No = TBL_PO.PO_No
WHERE TBL_PO.PO_No = @PO_No

UPDATE TBL_PO_Cart
SET TBL_PO_Cart.ISBN_No=@ISBN_No,TBL_PO_Cart.UnitPrice=@UnitPrice
,TBL_PO_Cart.OrderQuantity=@OrderQuantity,TBL_PO_Cart.Total=@Total
FROM TBL_PO 
INNER JOIN TBL_PO_Cart ON TBL_PO_Cart.PO_No = TBL_PO.PO_No
WHERE TBL_PO.PO_No = @PO_No
```

And if you are asking to update 2 tables with 1 statement, it is not possible.
No RDBMS will allow it. Instead you can have Single transaction which have 2 update statements, so that you can commit/rollback.

**Edit as per changed Question:**

As the error described, you can't update column which is imposed with [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) property. We are not suppose to touch identity column in general.

And for the purpose of filling gaps we are provided with temporary setting

> Identity_Insert

But as explained in below answer, you can delete the record and reinsert with the above setting ON. You can try this in your case.

[How to update Identity column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19155816/3752496)

Comment: Look at the table prefixes in the `SET` clause (which, BTW, aren't valid in SQL Server anyway). They *are* trying to update multiple tables.

Comment: I changed my question.So please help me.Thanks for your valuable comments