# Reset IDENTITY column whitout deleting all rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, primary-key, sql-server-identity

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [Permanent] [bit] NULL,
    [Idx] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Idx] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

that contains 1000 rows where [Permanent]=1 and 500.000 rows with [Permanent] NULL

In addition, I have a stored procedure (called **MySP**) that do the following steps:

1. DELETE FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Permanent] IS NULL
2. (lots of calculations)
3. INSERT results of point 2 into [MyTable]

MySP runs every day so the number of [Idx] increase very quickly as every day 500.000 rows are deleted and inserted.
My target is, during the execution of the SP, to reset the value of column [Idx] to mantain the max number of [Idx] lower possible.

**1st try**

I have tried to update with the following query at the end of MySP but the system gives me a (correct) error.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[Idx]=B.[Idx_new]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Idx],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Idx]) AS [Idx_new]
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
) B
ON A.[Idx]=B.[Idx]
```

**2nd try**
After reading the following two questions/answers

- [Reset identity seed after deleting records in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/reset-identity-seed-after-deleting-records-in-sql-server?rq=1)
- [How to update Identity Column in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155775/how-to-update-identity-column-in-sql-server)

I have add the following at the end of MySP

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, 1);
```

but also this doesn't not work as in [MyTable], differently from the situation of both quesions, remain some rows, so the is a concrete risk that [Idx] is not unique and that's not good as [Idx] is my primary key.

**How could I reset the identity column value and also the rows that still remains into [MyTable]?**

Comment: 1) Find the minimum id in the table
2) Dynamic code : `DBCC CHECKIDENT (' MyTable ', RESEED, <min_id + 1>);`

Comment: Bigint has a max value of 2^63, so the Earth will spiral into the sun before you use it up.  In general, you should not muck around with the identity column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  `@Killer Queen` suggest, I have solved using this snippet of code, which find the `MAX([Idx])` of `MyTable` after the `DELETE` and the reeseed the identity before the new `INSERT`.

It works because the rows with `[Permanent]=1` are the first rows inserted in the table so their `[Idx]` values start from 1 and are very low.

```
DELETE 
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Permanent]!=1 OR [Permanent] IS NULL

DECLARE @MaxIdx As bigint
SET @MaxIdx = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Idx]),0) FROM [MyTable])

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, @MaxIdx);
```

Comment: If another copy of the same sp executes concurrently, it can delete from table **BETWEEN** SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Idx]),0) FROM [MyTable] and DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, @MaxIdx);

Comment: If there are also concurrent INSERTS, they can INSERT **BETWEEN** SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Idx]),0) FROM [MyTable] and DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, @MaxIdx);