The multi-part identifier "S.clientid" could not be bound
SET IDENTITY_INSERT SurveyInformations ON

UPDATE SurveyInformations 
SET SurveyInformations.id = Master_Client_Update.id
WHERE Master_Client_Update.Client_Id = SurveyInformations.clientid 
  AND Master_Client_Update.emp_id = SurveyInformations.EmployeeId 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT SurveyInformations OFF

I'm trying to copy the values from the column id in table (master_client_update) to column id in table SurveyInformations.
But I get these errors:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "Master_Client_Update.Client_Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "Master_Client_Update.emp_id" could not be bound.

Thanks

please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155775/how-to-update-identity-column-in-sql-server   . I guess, you can not update IDENTITY-column

it is not about updating identity column, we can handle this by Set Identity but the main error is "The multi-part identifier could not be bound."

Please update your question with the full DDL for both tables, including any indexes/constraints

This error means that Master_Client_Update is not known to the query. You are naming the table you want to update but are not stating the source of the data to be used. Just using the name of the table in SET and WHERE clauses is not the way to go.
As for your options, you have multiple:

use UPDATE FROM - assuming there'll be only updates needed this might be the best option to go with:

UPDATE t
  SET t.id = s.id
FROM SurveyInformations AS t
INNER JOIN Master_Client_Update AS s
ON s.Client_Id=t.clientid AND s.emp_id=t.EmployeeId;


use MERGE - this might me unnecessary if the only thing you're doing is updating rows, but if by chance you want to also insert new rows this variant offers a concise way to write it - be aware though that you should know what are the possible complications (but that's true even for option 1 - see the note below):

merge SurveyInformations as t
using (select * from Master_Client_Update) as s
on s.Client_Id=t.clientid AND s.emp_id=t.EmployeeId
when matched then
update
set id = s.id;

Note:
If the statements should end up with multiple rows that could be the sources of the update, then the results are undefined, see the following for an answer, how to resolve that.

Thank you too much, appreciating your help.

one more issue: i'm updating 5 tables, one of those is the (SurveyInformations) that you helped me to do it and works fine, now i'm updating the other 4 tables it does not work because of the the rows * is not the same  in the source (Master_Client_Update) , one table is 55 row and other is 61 row and source is 285row , i got this error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Complaints'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Complaints'. The duplicate key value is (21)." i want to copy the (id) of the source into the destination even if there is no matching (client_id and employee_id)..

Why a MERGE..? There seems no benefit to using such a quirky feature here.

what should i use to do this task?!

@SpiderPro "creating rows in the target when they exist in the source?", well just add the when not matched then insert clause (if you are using MERGE).
OTOH: As pointed out by Thom A and I would rephrase it for this specific case: "Read the documentation and understand what the statements are doing in the first place"

@ThomA thx for the notes (btw. your link is broken, it should be .org instead of .com)
To your question, simply: for some reason I like the syntax better than UPDATE FROM; so it's purely personal. It's been a while since I've been doing some serious SQL stuff, so I do admit I'm not up to date in the best practices; although after reading some of the links that you mentioned, I wouldn't go as far as using the word quirky. It has its specifics and one needs to know under which circumstances to use it.
I'll update the answer a bit :)
