# Multiple identity columns specified for table exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have this initial migration:

```
namespace DataAccess.Migrations
{
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class init : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.SchoolclassCodes",
                c => new
                    {
                        Schoolclass = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Type = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Schoolclass);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.SchoolclassCodes");
        }
    }
}
```

The schoolclass property is of datatype integer and the primary key.

I have already data filled in the schoolclassCode table.

Now I changed the **datatype** from **integer** to **string** and created another migration:

```
namespace DataAccess.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class changedatattypeandaddedkeyId : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.SchoolclassCodes");
            AddColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AlterColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Schoolclass", c => c.String());
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Id");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.SchoolclassCodes");
            AlterColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Schoolclass", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            DropColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Id");
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Schoolclass");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the `update-database` I get the exception that multiple identity columns are not allowed for a table.

But I have nowhere multiple keys defined.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: That's a known issue - you will need to recreate the table. See Get's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153233/cant-remove-identity-attribute-from-pk

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```
AlterColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Schoolclass", c => c.String());
```

above

```
AddColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
```

So

```
public override void Up()
{
       DropPrimaryKey("dbo.SchoolclassCodes");
       AlterColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Schoolclass", c => c.String());
       AddColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
       AddPrimaryKey("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "Id");
}
```

Comment: I tried all sorts of reordering the migration methods and your suggestion returns this: Could not create IDENTITY attribute on nullable column 'schoolclass',  But where is the nullable string column 'schoolclass' and primary key column? The DropPrimaryKey is executed before the AlterColumn method !!! Thats not logical!

Comment: I correct: "...a primary key column?"

Comment: That won't work once you already have an identity field unless you recreate the table.

Comment: But when I recreate the table with the migration sql methods do I only have to do CreateTable("Schoolclasscode") and will my fluent configurations also be used?

Comment: @steve is right. You're going to have to manually script out  backup, drop, and recreate scripts using the Sql(); command.
Sql("//Select * INTO BackupTable From Original Table");
Sql("//Drop Existing Table");
Sql("//Create New Table");
Sql("//Restore Data From Back Up");
Sql("//Delete Backup");