# Re-Creating table in migration results in 'Invalid column name User_Id'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I open this question because of this unanswered/duplicate question of mine:

[Multiple identity columns specified for table exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317283/multiple-identity-columns-specified-for-table-exception)

The answer to this question is here:

[Cant remove identity attribute from PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153233/cant-remove-identity-attribute-from-pk)

in short: "***I have to Re-Create my sql table in the migration Up method***"

I have a User has many SchoolclassCode relation:

```
   public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SchoolclassCode> SchoolclassCodes { get; set; }
    }

public class SchoolclassCode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Schoolclass { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

That is my **INIT migration**

```
 public partial class Init: DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.SchoolclassCodes",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Schoolclass = c.String(),
                        Type = c.String(),
                        User_Id = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.User_Id)
                .Index(t => t.User_Id);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Users",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "User_Id", "dbo.Users");
            DropIndex("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", new[] { "User_Id" });
            DropTable("dbo.Users");
            DropTable("dbo.SchoolclassCodes");
        }
    }
```

That is my **Second migration** which is throwing the error: invalid column name 'User_Id' when I do `'Update-database'`

```
public partial class ReCreateTable : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            // backup schoolclassCodes table
            DropTable("SchoolclassCodes");
            CreateTable("SchoolclassCodes",
                c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Schoolclass = c.String(maxLength: 3), // 12a,7b
                    Type = c.String(),
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false,identity:false)
                })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(s => s.Schoolclass, unique: true);


            // Delete Table Users
            Sql("Delete from Users");

            // Re-Insert data
            SqlFile("./Migrations/data.sql");

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

What do I wrong, that the `update-database` fails?

Comment: Can you check which specific query throws this error using `update-database -verbose`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to delete everything you created in the first migration, drop them as described in the Down() code:

```
// backup schoolclassCodes table
DropForeignKey("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", "User_Id", "dbo.Users");
DropIndex("dbo.SchoolclassCodes", new[] { "User_Id" });
// DropTable("dbo.Users");
DropTable("dbo.SchoolclassCodes");
```

An observation, seems like you are coupling the need to keep your old data with migrations. I would separate the two.

First, save your old data. If the volume is low consider adding it to a Seed() method. Otherwise rename the tables in SQL and use SQL to repopulate them after migrations adds the corrected tables back.

Migrations are intended to let you build a database from your models, so I would delete both migrations and add a single new migration that represents your current model.

Comment: This application already runs in the wild, the other developers wont let me delete both migrations ;-). I am not going to delete everything I created in the first migration. I do not want to delete the Users table.

Comment: You should be able to keep the Users table, but you need to drop the FK constraint.

Comment: Now I did as you said also drop the Users table in your order then I get the error: Could not drop object 'dbo.Users' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. But BEFORe I do:             DropForeignKey("dbo.Schoolclasscodes", "UserId", "dbo.Users"); Why this error?

Comment: When I look under the Schoolclasscodes table Keys folder in SSMS: there is a black key with: FK_dbo.SchoolclassCodes_dbo.Users_Branch_Id

Comment: When I do: EXEC sp_fkeys 'SchooclassCodes' to get all FK`s on the table there is nothing, but I see the key in the SSMStudio :P