# Change Code First database table to have PK not be identity column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an MVC application using Code First data migrations and now, long after making a table, I'd like to change the PK column to not be an auto-generated Identity column.  But I get the impression I just can't do this without having CodeFirst delete the table somehow (which will be hard given all the dependencies) and recreate it? Really wishing I didn't have to do that.

What I've tried:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AssessmentID { get; set; }
```

and this in OnModelCreating():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Assessment>()
            .Property(e => e.AssessmentID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

When doing add-migration, it doesn't add anything. I tried manually adding this line but it does not update the db:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Assessment", "AssessmentID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity:false));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded that this is indeed not possible. Like the post below says, there is no SQL Alter command to change the Identity status on a column, so CodeFirst can't create one. I plan to remove all migration files and rescaffold (things have gotten messy in other ways).

[Remove Identity from a column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230257/sql-server-remove-identity-from-a-column-in-a-table)