# How to drop the identity column in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How to Drop the existing table  IDENTITY Field by using sql query.
 I have already tried the query like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Database.tableName OF
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230257/sql-server-remove-identity-from-a-column-in-a-table

Answer (score 1):

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT` allows you to explicitly insert values into an identity column, instead of having it auto-assign (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx).

As far as I am aware, you cannot drop the identity feature of an identity column; the only solution I can think of is to drop the column entirely:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
DROP COLUMN identityColumn
```

If for some reason you just want to "turn off" the identity feature for a while, and your table is not too large, you can just copy the identity column into a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD identityCopy int

UPDATE myTable
SET identityCopy = identityColumn
```

...and then drop the identity column. You can, of course, re-add a new identity column and copy over the values with `IDENTITY_INSERT` if/when you want to add it back.