# Identity Column not being modified by Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The relevant Entity is as follows:

```
public class FieldBookingDateRange : ITimeStamps, ICreatedBy, ISoftDeletable
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.None )]
    public int FieldBookingDateRangeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual FieldBooking FieldBooking { get; set; }

    public virtual DateRange DateRange { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

I have a database column that is currently set to Identity: true.

If i run the following auto generated migration on it (This should be setting the column to false on identity):

```
public partial class RemovedDBGen_FieldBookingDateRange : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges", new[] { "FieldBookingDateRangeID" });
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges");
        AlterColumn("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges", "FieldBookingDateRangeID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges", "FieldBookingDateRangeID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges", "FieldBookingDateRangeID");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges", new[] { "FieldBookingDateRangeID" });
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges");
        AlterColumn("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges", "FieldBookingDateRangeID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges", "FieldBookingDateRangeID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges", "FieldBookingDateRangeID");
    }
}
```

It doesn't do anything... But doesn't fail.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

SQL -Verbose output

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM sys.indexes 
    WHERE 
        name = N'IX_FieldBookingDateRangeID' AND 
        object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FieldBookingDateRanges]', N'U')
)
DROP INDEX [IX_FieldBookingDateRangeID] ON [dbo].[FieldBookingDateRanges]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FieldBookingDateRanges] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FieldBookingDateRanges] ALTER COLUMN [FieldBookingDateRangeID] [int] NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FieldBookingDateRanges] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.FieldBookingDateRanges] PRIMARY KEY ([FieldBookingDateRangeID])
CREATE INDEX [IX_FieldBookingDateRangeID] ON [dbo].[FieldBookingDateRanges]([FieldBookingDateRangeID])
```

Comment: Can you show a generated SQL script?

Comment: I've done that for you... Going to check over it myself too.

Comment: It seems i have to completely drop the table in order to modify it :S ?

Comment: It might be a limitation of SQL Server. I remember I had to do that a while ago, but can't find any documentation to that effect.

Comment: Some explanation of why you have the problem  over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't remove the identity property from a column once it's set. However you might be able to modify the automatically generated migration to implement a workaround.

You can find some examples here:

- [Remove Identity from a column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230257/sql-server-remove-identity-from-a-column-in-a-table)

  > If you need to keep the data, but remove the IDENTITY column, you will need to:
  >
  > - Create a new column
  > - Transfer the data from the existing IDENTITY column to the new column
  > - Drop the existing IDENTITY column.
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87420/how-to-remove-identity-specification-for-multiple-tables