# Entity Framework set auto increment and start value on column that is not primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

We use Entity Framework. And I have an issue with a table in the DB.

The Id is a `GUID` where we create a new `GUID` manually.
Now I want to implement a new column to auto increment and I want this to start at 100000000.
To make the column auto increment is working ok (I think)

```
 Company {
    private Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required, Range(10000000, 999999999)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual long StakeholderNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 }
```

When adding the migration, I get this migrationfile;

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Companies", "StakeholderNumber", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        CreateIndex("dbo.Companies", "StakeholderNumber", unique: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Companies", new[] { "StakeholderNumber" });
        AlterColumn("dbo.Companies", "StakeholderNumber", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
    }
```

This looks to work.
BUT I want the stakeholderNumber to start at 100000000 instead of 1.
From other examples, this could work by setting stakeholdernumber to `primary` and then add the line:

```
        Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.Companies', RESEED, 100000000);");
```

BUT I do not want stakeholdernumber to be `primary`!

If I run this with updadte-database, I get this error:

> Companies' does not contain an identity column

SO is there a way to set auto increment on Stakeholdernumber to 10000000 without making the column `primary`?

Comment: Can you show the complete example - the original entity model/configuration and modified entity/configuration.

Comment: Actually the issue is that the migration does **not** change the existing column to `IDENTITY`. Take a look at [Migrate entity with updated DatabaseGeneratedOption in Entity-Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462749/migrate-entity-with-updated-databasegeneratedoption-in-entity-framework) to get some ideas how to resolve it.

Comment: what about just setting the default value in SQL to MAX+1, instead of trying to use entity framework to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and ended using sequence instead. I defined a sequence and then used it like so

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.HasSequence<int>("MySequence", schema: "shared").StartsAt(10000000).IncrementsBy(1);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .Property(o => o.StakeholderNumber)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR shared.MySequence");            
    }
```

Works perfect for me. I am using EF core 2.0.
Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there an EF 6 way to do this? Can't find it and need to do the same thing on a legacy project.