# Insert distinct records from column in Table1 into column table 2 into row where they match on a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-insert, sql-server-2014

[image]

The first table I want to move the `Product.ProductName` column into the second table called `Inventory.ProductName` but delete all the duplicate entries.  This I can do, but when I insert these distinct values into `Inventory.ProductName`, it creates rows for them instead of associating them with the correct `ProductID`.  Can't wrap my head around this one.  Here's what I tried.

```
insert into dbo.Inventory (ProductName)
select distinct Product.ProductName
from dbo.Product
inner join dbo.Inventory on (Product.Name = Inventory.ProductID)
```

Comment: `UPDATE` not `INSERT`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Merge Statement:

```
MERGE Inventory AS target
USING (SELECT Name, ProductName FROM Product) AS source (ProductID, ProductName)
ON (target.ProductID = source.ProductID)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET Name = source.ProductName
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT (ProductID, Name)
VALUES (source.ProductID, source.ProductName);
```

You can find more here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb510625(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: I liked this answer because I didn't know about MERGE, but I got this error `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Inventory' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`  I know you can turn it `ON` but I wondered if the query cannot be changed to avoid this error in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, you can change the Insert statement, but the problem becomes when you need to relate to the Product table, because you´ll be using different ProductID. So, you should maintain the same ProductID for both tables in order to make a correct inner join.

Comment: I see... the best approach should be create a new column for Inventory which will be the Identity, and you must use the same query I provided you inserting the ProductID, in order to maintain the relationship between tables.

Comment: Trying to do this but  I keep getting this error when I run the query 
`alter table dbo.Inventory 
add ID int Identity(1,1);`
`Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Inventory'. Only one identity column per table is allowed`

Comment: Have you removed the identity from ProductID? First remove it, then add the new column with the Identity.

Comment: According to this answer I can't remove the Identity unless I drop the entire column. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230257/sql-server-remove-identity-from-a-column-in-a-table

Comment: Oh... I haven't used SQL Server since a couple years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The rough syntax you are looking for is:

```
UPDATE dbo.Inventory 
SET ProductName = Product.ProductName
FROM 
    dbo.Inventory 
     INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Product ON 
        Inventory.ProductID = Product.Name
```

This will set the Product Name in `Inventory` equal to the Product Name in `Product`. Note that you will have an issue if multiple versions of `Product.ProductName` exist for a distinct `Product.Name`.