# How to remove identity on primary key column in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016

How to remove identity on primary key column in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Identity from a column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230257/remove-identity-from-a-column-in-a-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new column, copy the data, drop original column

```
alter table yourtable
add newcolumn int

update yourtable
set newcolumn=oldcolumn

alter table yourtable
drop column oldcolumn
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But My identity column is a foreign key for other tables.

Comment: Remove all the foreign key constraints and then put them back when you are done - see the link above in the comments section for more detail

Comment: How to turn off the identity on column and turn on the auto increament as column is referred as foreign key on other table?

Comment: Foreign key on the other table is the value that points to the primary key of another table - remove all foreign keys pointing the your identity column and then recreate them pointing to the new column when you are done

Answer (score -4):

you can't remove Identity on a primary key column.  It is by default gets created when you choose a column as Primary.  You need to do alternatives which I don't recommend on project tables.

1) Drop the primary key with cascade option (You will lose the links to child tables)

2)
- You need to create another column with a different name in the same table.
- copy that data into newly created column
- Delete the primary key column.
this will leave orphan records in child tables that are being referenced.

Comment: This is incorrect, SQL Server primary key columns are not identity fields by default.