# Remove auto increment By Script SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server how to drop identity from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702745/sql-server-how-to-drop-identity-from-a-column)

How I alter a Table by script to remove autoindenty of a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add new NON-autoincrementing column of the same type with default constraint to your identity column
- drop default constraint
- drop identity column
- rename new column to old one with [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx)

Comment: Not necessary. [You can do it without modifying the data pages at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7327065/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith Not found @ link, please, provide more info

Comment: The link gives an example script starting off with a table with `identity` and ending without one. Not sure what more info you require.