# Drop and recreate constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to drop and recreate IX_DimCountry CONSTRAINT

```
CREATE TABLE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimCountry] (
    [Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [IX_DimCountry] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and to have this

```
CREATE TABLE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimCountry] (
    [Id]           INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [IX_DimCountry] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [WH_IX]
```

And also is there a way just to alter Id to not be IDENTITY anymore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Alter Constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244889/how-to-alter-constraint)

Comment: Please refer this post: [How to remove auto increment from table in sql server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511309/how-to-remove-auto-increment-from-table-in-sql-server-2012)

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimCountry] DROP CONSTRAINT IX_DimCountry;


ALTER TABLE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimCountry]
ADD CONSTRAINT IX_DimCountry UNIQUE(id)
```

You cannot Remove IDENTITY.

[Remove Identity from a column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230257/sql-server-remove-identity-from-a-column-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the data, but remove the IDENTITY column, you will need to:

Create a new column
Transfer the data from the existing IDENTITY column to the new column
Drop the existing IDENTITY column.
Rename the new column to the original column name